# Решение проблемы с путем для файла

Tags: python

temp = ['Lenin', 'Olga', 'Stalin', 'Yaroslav Mudriy']

```
for x in range(len(temp)):
    name1 = random.choice(temp)
    temp.remove(name1)
    # print(name1)
    print('person\\age1\\',name1)
```

Почему то выводит пути вот так, с пробелом:

`person\age1\ Stalin
person\age1\ Lenin
person\age1\ Yaroslav Mudriy
person\age1\ Olga`

Между слешем есть пробел, как от него избавиться?

Comment: `print('person\\age1\\{0}'.format(name1))`

Comment: или `print('person\\age1\\', name1, sep='')`

Comment: Спасибо, выручили